# Transfer function of controller

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

[image]

I am solving this question given in book (Automatic control system). As asked in (a) part $G_c(s)$ of the controller. I solved it and getting answer$$G_c(s) = \frac{F(s)}{E_c(s)}=\frac{100}{s}-\frac{30}{s+6}+\frac{70}{s+10}$$ but the answer in manual is $$G_c(s) = \frac{F(s)}{E_c(s)}=s(\frac{100}{s}-\frac{30}{s+6}+\frac{70}{s+10})$$ 
I know laplace transform and i am not too mature in control theory so please help in solving this question.
I want to know from where this $s$ in multiplication is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue is really about control theory.  It is about notation.

The LT of the numerator, $F(s)$, is precisely the quantity in parentheses.  That is including the step function factor $u_s(t)$.  Thus, you cannot simply cancel the $u_s(t)$ from the numerator and denominator.

Thus, the LT of the denominator, $E_C(s)$, is the LT of the unit step function $u_s(t)$, or $1/s$.  That accounts for the missing factor of $s$ in the answer.